# Turn off annoying paths in formula bar

Tags: excel, path, formula

I have an Excel workbook which refers to itself with fully qualified paths in the formula bar.
Instead of Sheet1.A1 it will display

```
[full_path_to_this_workbook]Sheet1.A1
```

How can I get rid of this Feature and have it display Sheet1.A1 instead?

Comment: Is that workbook in a network folder?

Comment: @csanjose: I copied it from a Network Folder to a local one. No matter where I open it from, the phenomenon persists.

Comment: It happened to me sometime ago with a shared workbook. Im afraid you will have to edit all formulae manually